# Running Protractor for the first time on a container and it fails with errors

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver-manager

I'm running a Protractor Sample application and it fails on the container.
I tried the same application ona  physical machine and it works as expected and passses the test case.

My Test code: -->CheckTitleSpec.js

```
//CheckTitleSpec.js2
describe('Protractor Demo', function() {
it('to check the page title', function() {
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.get('https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/');
browser.driver.getTitle().then(function(pageTitle) {
expect(pageTitle).toEqual('Software Testing Help - Free Software        Testing & IT Tutorials and Courses');
});
});
});
```

The conf.js File

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800x600"]
    }
    },
    specs: ['CheckTitleSpec.js']
    };
```

The Docker file for building the Container:

```
FROM node:latest
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common
RUN apt-get install default-jre -y
RUN npm install -g protractor
RUN webdriver-manager update
RUN npm install protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter
# Install Chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-  stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb -y
COPY CheckTitleSpec.js /
COPY conf.js /
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "protractor /conf.js" ]
```

On the container the output is:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_212"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b12, mixed mode)

webdriver-manager version
I/version - webdriver-manager 12.1.4

node -v
v11.12.0

npm -v
6.7.0

protractor --version
Version 5.4.2

google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 74.0.3729.131

   protractor conf.js
[10:32:53] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[10:32:53] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[10:32:55] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at     http://172.17.0.2:49496/wd/hub
[10:32:56] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited    abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6   (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-  heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.9.125-linuxkit x86_64) (WARNING: The   server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 147 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '153e772db9cd', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux',  os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.125-linuxkit', java.version:  '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[10:32:56] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed   to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is  no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6    (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch- heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.9.125-linuxkit x86_64) (WARNING: The   server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 147 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:   '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '153e772db9cd', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux',  os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.125-linuxkit', java.version:  '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules   /protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor  /node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor /node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules /protractor/n  ode_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at createDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:626:16)
    at Local.getNewDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
at q.then.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules /protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[10:32:56] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

I tested the same code on a Physical Linux box headless and it works as expected.

Any leads is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: before starting protractor try running `export DISPLAY=:99` if helps please let me know I'll the full answer

Comment: Nope. Same error. I tried to set the display but it still fails

Comment: I was seeing this error when I have not installed xvfb, but you run tests in headless anyway... try to follow directions from this page http://www.tothenew.com/blog/protractor-with-jenkins-and-headless-chrome-xvfb-setup/

Answer (score 1):

I've seen several answers similar to the one posted [here](https://club.ministryoftesting.com/t/unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-error-is-displayed-in-console-on-executing-test-in-chrome-browser/16818/2). Those answers suggest using `--no-sandbox` and `--disable-dev-shm-usage` flags as a workaround.

In your config, add these flags like so:

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly now. The challenge is now to stitch this whole thing into a Jenkins Pipeline. Thank you for the Solution and the link. It helps a lot. :-)